# Running "php artisan migrate" in Ubuntu Terminal returning Error

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04, artisan-migrate

```
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = crosssolardevelopment and table_name = migrations)

  at /var/www/ProjectNAme/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668|
```

I have uncommented the line

```
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

in php.ini also have restarted the apache2

And this is my .env

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:nWy9Nrplqo0EV74hQCODrkZW0A0Y7WabpdVHm3AD5Qo=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=dbdevelopment
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Im wondering why I still get the error

Comment: Maybe your PHP-CLI has a seperate `php.ini` where you need to activate the extension? At least on Debian it is seperated, though using `phpenmod` would enable it for both.

Comment: Im sorry I dont know if I have how can i check it? @TobiasK.

Comment: `php -i` includes that info, use something like `php -i | grep pdo`.

Comment: @TobiasK. let me check this in terminal be right back

Comment: @TobiasK. it is also uncommented it is like this `; configuration for php common module
; priority=10
extension=pdo.so
`

Comment: Only `pdo` (no `mysql`) is not enough. It should at least return: 
`/etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini, \
/etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini, \
API Extensions => mysqli,pdo_mysql \
pdo_mysql`

Comment: I suggest you try `phpenmod pdo_mysql` instead of manually editing `.ini` files. Given Ubuntu is a Debian derivate it **might** work.